# gpg-agent not working since 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, gnupg

I was starting my gpg-agent like this in my `.bashrc` file

```
[ -f ~/.gpg-agent-info ] && source ~/.gpg-agent-info
if [ -S "${GPG_AGENT_INFO%%:*}" ]; then
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
else
  eval $( gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file ~/.gpg-agent-info )
fi

GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

Since the upgrade to 16.04 when I log in I receive this message:

```
gpg-agent[11727]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent[11728]: gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.1.11 started
S.gpg-agent is written in .gnupg/
```

So `write-env-file` is not longer supported.  I can no longer enter my gpg password in the pinentry dialogue box and have gpg reuse this, which I could under Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I set this up in 16.04?

Comment: The gpg-agent starts.  
When I use gpg to view a gpg protected file:
gpg --decrypt cat-me.txt.gpg
I receive the message:
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
Before the upgrdae to Ubuntu 16.04 I would recieve a pop up box.  this would save the gpg details, so next time I did gpg --decrypt I would not have to enter a gpg password.

Comment: OK.  The issue seems to be that gpg-agent 2.1.11 does not set the GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable.
If I export GPG_AGENT_INFO to point to the socket file ie.|export GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/<user>/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:12065:1 with the pid and owner pid then I get the pinentry box for the passphrase.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that gpg-agent 2.1.11 does not set the GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable. 
If I export GPG_AGENT_INFO to point to the socket file ie.|export GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home//.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:12065:1 with the pid and owner pid then I get the pinentry box for the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

On my 16.04.1 LTS the options file `gpg.conf` located in `~/.gnupg` was missing. I created one with the option `use-agent` (Just like on my other old Ubuntu 14.04-LTS) and it worked.